# JQuery get value from one td to another

Tags: jquery, input, get, html-table

I have this code

```
<table class="X">
  <tr>
    <td class="Y">Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Z">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="edit-Y" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get value from td with class "Y" to input with class "edit-Y" with jQuery.
I tried to code scripts in a different way, but anytime i got empty field or [Object Object]. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Post what you tried so we can answer the question quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
$('.edit-Y').val($('.Y').html());
```

***Additional answer for the comment***

If you have html like the following and you want to select each value in td and insert it the specific input boxes,

```
<table class="X">
  <tr>
    <td class="Y1">Value1</td>
    <td class="Y2">Value2</td>
    <td class="Y3">Value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Z">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="edit-Y1" type="text">
    <input class="edit-Y2" type="text">
    <input class="edit-Y3" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jquery would do like this,

```
$(function(){
 $('td[class^=Y]').each(function(){ 
    var tdValue = $(this).html();
    var id = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.edit-'+id).val(tdValue);
  });
});
```

Comment: It works. And if i have Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4 and edit-Y1,edit-Y2,edit-Y3 rows, how I can minimize the size of code and not write 4 same lines of jQuery code?

Comment: Actually the second table pops up after clicking a button so the classes are not edit-y1/edit-y2. It's just edit-y. For example if i click button #3 it pop ups with information which is in td with class Y3.

Answer (score 1):

More universal approach:

```
$(".Z input").val(function() {
    return $(".X td." + this.className.split("-").pop()).text();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/G3tBT/

Answer (score 0):

`$('.edit-Y').val( $('td.Y').text() );`